# Selenium Show A Custom Message Instead Of "TimeOut"

Tags: selenium, timeout, wait

I'm writing a test code with Selenium. I'm waiting for an element like this:

```
WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Link Text")));
```

I need to show a custom message instead of time out message if expected element doesn't come.

I used withMessage() method bu is not working in this situation.

```
webDriverWait.withMessage("message");
```

How can I show a custom message instead of a time out message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the timeOutException and at that point provide your own custom error message. Something like:

```
try {
  WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
  webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Link Text")));
} catch(TimeOutException e) {
  System.out.println("[DEBUG] Could not find element in allowed time...")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did like you said and it's okey.